# Javascript - NaN.undefined as textholder problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a problem at the coding project I am doing, as I formatted the numbers to be shown nicer, I ran into a problem. The webpage when it loads shows `NaN`. undefined in the total income/expenses at the top. I can't figure out what is the problem.

```js
//Budget controller
var budgetController = (function() {
  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
    this.percentage = -1;
  };

  Expense.prototype.calcPercentage = function(totalIncome) {
    if (totalIncome > 0) {
      this.percentage = Math.round((this.value / totalIncome) * 100);
    } else {
      this.percentage = -1;
    }
  };

  Expense.prototype.getPercentage = function() {
    return this.percentage;
  };

  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var calculateTotal = function(type) {
    var sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur) {
      sum = sum + cur.value;
    });
    data.totals[type] = sum;
  };

  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },
    totals: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    },
    budget: 0,
    percentage: -1
  };

  return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;

      //create new iD
      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      //CREATe new item, if it is inc or exp
      if (type === 'exp') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
      } else if (type === 'inc') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }

      // Push all items  into data structure and return the new element
      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
      return newItem;
    },

    deleteItem: function(type, id) {
      var ids, index;

      ids = data.allItems[type].map(function(current) {
        return current.id;
      });

      index = ids.indexOf(id);

      if (index !== -1) {
        data.allItems[type].splice(index, 1);
      }
    },

    calculateBudget: function() {
      // calculate the total income and expenses
      calculateTotal('exp');
      calculateTotal('inc');

      // calculate the budget: income - expenses
      data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;

      if (data.totals.inc > 0) {
        data.percentage = Math.round((data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc) * 100);
      } else {
        data.percentage = -1;
      }
    },

    calculatePercentages: function() {
      data.allItems.exp.forEach(function(cur) {
        cur.calcPercentage(data.totals.inc);
      });
    },

    getPercentages: function() {
      var allPerc = data.allItems.exp.map(function(cur) {
        return cur.getPercentage();
      });
      return allPerc;
    },

    getBudget: function() {
      return {
        budget: data.budget,
        totalInc: data.totals.inc,
        totalExp: data.totals.exp,
        percentage: data.percentage
      };
    }
  };
})();

// UI Controller
var UIController = (function() {
  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputBtn: '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.income__list',
    expensesContainer: '.expenses__list',
    budgetLabel: '.budget__value',
    incomeLabel: '.budget__income--value',
    expensesLabel: '.budget__expenses--value',
    percentageLabel: '.budget__expenses--percentage',
    container: '.container',
    expensesPercLabel: '.item__percentage',
    dateLabel: '.budget__title--month'
  };

  var formatNumber = function(num, type) {
    var numSplit, int, dec, type;
    /* + or - befofe a number 
    on 2 decimals
    comma seperating thousands

    */
    num = Math.abs(num);
    num = num.toFixed(2);

    numSplit = num.split('.');

    int = numSplit[0];

    if (int.length > 3) {
      int = int.substr(0, int.length - 3) + ',' + int.substr(int.length - 3, 3); //input 23510, output 23,510
    }

    dec = numSplit[1];

    return (type === 'exp' ? '-' : '+') + ' ' + int + '.' + dec;
  };

  var nodeListForEach = function(list, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      callback(list[i], i);
    }
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, //will be either inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value)
      };
    },

    addListItem: function(obj, type) {
      var html, newHtml, element;
      // Create HTML string with placeholder text

      if (type === 'inc') {
        element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%"> <div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      } else if (type === 'exp') {
        element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      }

      // Replace the placeholder text with some actual data
      newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', formatNumber(obj.value, type));

      // Insert the HTML into the DOM
      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
    },

    deleteListItem: function(selectorID) {
      var el = document.getElementById(selectorID);
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    },

    clearFields: function() {
      var fields, fieldsArr;

      fields = document.querySelectorAll(
        DOMstrings.inputDescription + ',' + DOMstrings.inputValue
      );

      fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

      fieldsArr.forEach(function(current, index, array) {
        current.value = "";
      });

      fieldsArr[0].focus();
    },

    displayBudget: function(obj) {
      var type;
      obj.budget > 0 ? type = 'inc' : type = 'exp';

      document.querySelector(DOMstrings.budgetLabel).textContent = formatNumber(obj.budget, type);
      document.querySelector(DOMstrings.incomeLabel).textContent = formatNumber(obj.totalInc, 'inc');
      document.querySelector(DOMstrings.expensesLabel).textContent = formatNumber(obj.totalExp, 'exp');

      if (obj.percentage > 0) {
        document.querySelector(DOMstrings.percentageLabel).textContent = obj.percentage + '%';
      } else {
        document.querySelector(DOMstrings.percentageLabel).textContent = '---';
      }
    },

    displayPercentages: function(percentages) {
      var fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);

      nodeListForEach(fields, function(current, index) {
        if (percentages[index] > 0) {
          current.textContent = percentages[index] + '%';
        } else {
          current.textContent = '---';
        }
      });
    },

    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    }
  };
})();

// App Controller - global
var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var setupEventListeners = function() {
    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        ctrlAddItem();
      }
    });

    document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click', ctrlDeleteItem);
  };

  var updateBudget = function() {
    // 1. Calculate the budget
    budgetCtrl.calculateBudget();

    // 2. Return the budget
    var budget = budgetCtrl.getBudget();

    // 3. Display the budget on the UI
    UICtrl.displayBudget(budget);
  };

  var updatePercentages = function() {
    // 1. Calculate percentages
    budgetCtrl.calculatePercentages();

    // 2. Read percentages from the budget controller
    var percentages = budgetCtrl.getPercentages();

    // 3. Update the UI with the new percentages
    UICtrl.displayPercentages(percentages);
  };

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input, newItem;

    // 1. Get the field input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();

    if (input.description !== "" && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0) {
      // 2. Add the item to the budget controller
      newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

      // 3. Add the item to the UI
      UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);

      // 4. Clear the fields
      UICtrl.clearFields();

      // 5. Calculate and update budget
      updateBudget();

      // 6. Calculate and update percentages
      updatePercentages();
    }
  };

  var ctrlDeleteItem = function(event) {
    var itemID, splitID, type, ID;

    itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;

    if (itemID) {
      //inc-1
      splitID = itemID.split('-');
      type = splitID[0];
      ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);

      // 1. delete the item from the data structure
      budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);

      // 2. Delete the item from the UI
      UICtrl.deleteListItem(itemID);

      // 3. Update and show the new budget
      updateBudget();

      // 4. Calculate and update percentages
      updatePercentages();
    }
  };

  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log('App has started');

      UICtrl.displayBudget({
        budget: 0,
        totalIncome: 0,
        totalExpenses: 0,
        percentage: -1
      });
      setupEventListeners();
    }
  };
})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: #FF5049 !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important;
}


/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
  height: 40vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.budget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
  background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/


/***** FORM *****/

.add {
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description {
  width: 400px;
}

.add__value {
  width: 100px;
}

.add__btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #28B9B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/***** LISTS *****/

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses__title {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item {
  padding: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item__description {
  float: left;
}

.item__value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #FFDAD9;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item__delete {
  float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item__delete--btn {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover .item__value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.item:hover .item__percentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.unpaid {
  background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF5049;
}

.unpaid .item__percentage {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.unpaid:hover .item__description {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you try and produce the minimal script example that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: It doesn't show me any error, just on webpage the value is presented as NaN.undefined when its refreshed. But when I put some values in it works great.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the emphasis being on the **minimal**

Comment: did you made a typo in this part `document.querySelector(DOMstrings.incomeLabel).textContent = formatNumber(obj.totalInc, 'inc');
      document.querySelector(DOMstrings.expensesLabel).textContent = formatNumber(obj.totalExp, 'exp');`. The object `obj` dosent contains the key you are trying to access. Make sure you are accessing the right key. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the function formatNumber, the value num is not initialized at first time. For solving this, you can put a default value when the value of num is empty, like this:

```js
var formatNumber = function(num = 0, type = '') {
    var numSplit, int, dec, type;
    /* + or - befofe a number 
    on 2 decimals
    comma seperating thousands

    */
    num = Math.abs(num);
    num = num.toFixed(2);

    numSplit = num.split('.');

    int = numSplit[0];

    if (int.length > 3) {
      int = int.substr(0, int.length - 3) + ',' + int.substr(int.length - 3, 3); //input 23510, output 23,510
    }

    dec = numSplit[1];

    return (type === 'exp' ? '-' : '+') + ' ' + int + '.' + dec;
  };
```